# Mysql Select that can manipulate the content of other cell

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I was wondering  with MySql possible to create a query that can
manipulate the content of some cell in function of the value of other cell

Example: this is the table with a SELECT ALL

`[id] [pre]  [Name] [Cat]   [Telef] [Email]`
`1      0     Rob    Alf     123     Rob@mail.com`

`2      1     Bob    Bet     456     Bob@mail.com`

`3      1     Fob    Alf     789     Fob@mail.com`

`4      0     Gob    Tan     101     Gob@mail.com`

`5      1     Nob    Ran     121     Nob@mail.com`

`6      0     Lob    Lan     141     Lob@mail.com`

the query should be something like this:
SELECT ALL BUT IF in cell of column [Pre] the value is = 0 the for
that row empty the cell of column [Cat] AND [Telef]

`[id] [pre]  [Name] [Cat]   [Telef] [Email]`
`1      0     Rob    " "     " "     Rob@mail.com`

`2      1     Bob    Bet     456     Bob@mail.com`

`3      1     Fob    Alf     789     Fob@mail.com`

`4      0     Gob    " "     " "     Gob@mail.com`

`5      1     Nob    Ran     121     Nob@mail.com`

`6      0     Lob    " "     " "     Lob@mail.com`

thanks

Comment: It would be better practice to perform those two task in sequence, for example: UPDATE table SET cat='', telef='' WHERE pre=0... followed by the query of SELECT ALL.  Because you are still wanting "all rows returned" regardless of the manipulation.

Comment: Duplication of existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344013/mysql-select-and-update-in-one-query